# window scroll bar hit bottom query more data

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300){
//query data & append
}
```

I have a page detect scroll bar - query data & append.

My problem is when I check 'network' from browser

it send query 3 or 4 times per scroll.(because mouse wheel scroll down very fast)

Is any way to solve this so I don't need to query unnecessary data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//set a variable for apply event

var start=1; // now below event work

if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300) && start){
start=0;// now it set 0 it s not work until your work done
//query data & append
start=1 //now your work done and it comes it this action again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if an ajax call(query) was made already, like this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300){
    if(!ajaxCall)
    {
        ajaxCall = true;
        //query data & append
        if (success)
            ajaxCall = false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to declare your `ajaxCall` somewhere in your code so it will not end in the global scope.

What this does is:

- initialize a variable to check if a request has been made already
- if no request was made, set the variable to `true` and make a request
- when the request comes back with a `success`, set it to `false`

Answer (score 1):

A smarter way to achieve this is to detect the end of scroll event on each scroll and write the code in it:

```
var delay = 1000;
var timeout = null;
$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
     alert('scrolling stopped');
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300){
     //query data & append
 }},delay);
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Why is it smarter ? Waiting for the scroll to end would create the impression of delay to the end user.

Comment: @Andrei: which is still faster than making ajax calls and checking if its already done. also your code will not work for second scroll unless first request has got completed.

Comment: For the end user it is not faster. And that was the hole point of the OP, for other ajax calls to not be made until the previous one succeeds so he will not get the same content appended multiple times.

Comment: Also there is no need to make other call if the previous didn't return since you would request the same `data page` from the server. That is pointless. P.S. your code requests the same `data` multiple times.

Comment: @Andrei:how are you so sure that it calls the same data. if that would have been the case then OP would have not called it on each scroll.

Comment: Because of the title `window scroll bar hit bottom query more data`. That sounds like an infinite scroll that will request the next page of data when the scroll is near the end. If the user didn't receive the next page, there is no point in calling for what is even further.